# Name changes for different app versions & avoiding spamming on the App Store

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, spam

I have posted 2 apps on the App Store that are only for the iPad.

I now want to post the iPhone versions for the same apps.

However, I have read that Apple Guidelines state that developers spamming the App Store with many versions of similar apps will have their accounts terminated.

So I basically want to ask 2 questions:

1. To avoid spamming, should I not post the iPhone versions at all or post Universal app versions?
2. Apple asks to change name if posting same app for a different device. For iPad, I can say "game_name HD". But what about naming for the iPhone? I was thinking "game_name Pro".

Would appreciate any help very much. Thanks.

Comment: Apple created that rule when some developers were spamming the store with dozens, even hundreds of similar apps.  4 is a smaller number.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah so I think making an iPhone version would be all right. In future I would be making only Universal apps. Can you suggest name changes for the iPhone though?

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have used the term "Pocket" for the iPhone/iPod Touch version. As in, Barnyard Bluegrass Pocket Edition.